# cannot change the size of the boxes in muiotpinput

Tags: material-ui, mui-x

I'm currently working on implementing OTP functionality using the **`muiotpinput`** package in my project. I have successfully designed rectangular OTP input fields, but I'm facing challenges in getting the desired shape when using the **`muiotpinput`** component.

I have attempted to modify the width, height, and other CSS properties, but the input fields remain in an oval shape instead of the desired rectangular form. I have checked the package documentation and tried different approaches, but haven't achieved the desired outcome.

If anyone has experience with the **`muiotpinput`** package and knows how to customize the shape of the OTP input, specifically to make it rectangular instead of oval